# Amazon CloudFront creates a new connection to Wowza Streaming Engine for each user

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront, live-streaming, wowza

We are using Wowza Streaming Engine for live streaming, and thought we can use Amazon CloudFront to deliver the video to viewers to reduce the load on our servers and stop worrying how much bandwidth we consume.

Users use HLS to watch the video on iOS devices, the URLs look like this: `http://[cdnHash].cloudfront.net/live/[origin]_[stream_name]/playlist.m3u8`. We have a number of servers across the world, so we created several Behaviours in CloudFront, so it knows where to get each stream, depending on the `[origin]` piece of the URL as Path Pattern.

This works, we can view the video using this URL, and all seems fine. However, we noticed that for every viewer using CloudFront URL, a new connection to Wowza Engine is created. Which kinda defeats the purpose of using a CDN, because the bandwidth from our servers is again directly proportional to the number of viewers, plus we'll be now paying for CloudFront bandwidth as well.

I am not sure where to look for the root of this problem: settings on Wowza origins, or CloudFront settings?

Comment: What about the HTTP response headers from CloudFront? Specifically, `X-Cache:`?  Or CloudFront hit/miss/error reports? Or CloudFront logs?  Of course you're going to initially see about the same number of connections... because your content isn't yet cached, and for each edge with a viewer request for an object, the content has to be fetched and cached before it can be served from cache.  The question that must be answered before anything else is whether your content is *ever* being served from cache... and content being fetched from the origin doesn't provide a conclusive "no" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the incorrect application type in your Wowza Streaming Engine. To integrate your Wowza with CloudFront, you will need to use an HTTP Origin type of application. When in this mode, connections are session-less and should not spawn unique connections for each CloudFront playback.

To create an HTTP Origin type of application:

1. From the Manager UI, go into Applications, and click on the Add Application menu.
2. Select either Live or VOD HTTP Origin depending on the type of content you are streaming.
3. Save your new application and test streaming from your CloudFront distribution again.